Sentinel 2 and Landsat 8 exported images close to black pixels
I am working with Landsat 8 and Sentinel 2 imagery for a specific location and period. Some exported images appear close to black, either entirely or partly. I'm unsure what the issue might be in my code.
Below is the function I use to collect the images.
def collect_satellite(dir, data, buffer_dis, collect, date, filter, bands, vis, satellite):
  os.makedirs(f'/content/{dir}', exist_ok=True)
  exist_scenes = set()

  # for lat, lon in data['loc']:
  lat, lon = map(float, data['loc'])
  region = ee.Geometry.Point(lon, lat).buffer(buffer_dis)

  if satellite == 'landsat':
    dataset = ee.ImageCollection(collect) \
              .filterDate(date[0], date[1]) \
              .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER', 'less_than', filter) \
              .filterBounds(region)

    select_bands = dataset.select(bands)

    select_vis = {
        'min': 0,
        'max': 65455
    }

    file_dir = f'/content/{dir}'
    geemap.ee_export_image_collection(select_bands, file_dir, scale=30, region=region, file_per_band=False)

  elif satellite == 'sentinel':
    dataset = ee.ImageCollection(collect) \
          .filterDate(date[0], date[1]) \
          .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', filter)) \
          .filterBounds(region)

    select_bands = dataset.select(bands)

    def norm_color(image):
      return image.visualize(**select_vis)

    select_vis = {
        'min': 0,
        'max': 3000
    }

    filtered_bands = select_bands.map(norm_color)
    file_dir = f'/content/{dir}'
    geemap.ee_export_image_collection(filtered_bands, file_dir, scale=30, region=region, file_per_band=False)

  if vis:
    Map = geemap.Map(center=[lat, lon], zoom=8)
    Map.addLayer(select_bands, select_vis, 'True Color')
    Map.addLayer(ee.Geometry.Point(lon, lat), {'color': 'red'}, 'Point');
    display(Map)

Below is how I call the functions.
# test landsat satellite imagery
collect = 'LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2'
date_range = ['2023-11-01', '2024-2-01']
select_bands = ['SR_B4', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B2']
collect_satellite('landsatImg', test_data, 20000, collect, date_range, 20, select_bands, True, 'landsat')

collect = 'COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED'
date_range = ['2023-11-01', '2024-2-01']
select_bands = ['B4', 'B3', 'B2']
collect_satellite('sentinelImg', test_data, 20000, collect, date_range, 20, select_bands, True, 'sentinel')

The exported images look like this
enter image description here
enter image description here
Also, is there any easier approach to collect these images (beginner friendly)? Earth Engine is powerful but it seems to be very complex. I didn't find a good guidance to learn how to use it. Thank you!
